# Static code analysis on TFS server 2010 and VS 2010 professional

Tags: tfs

I have installed TFS Server 2010. In the build definition I have enabled code analyis as "Always". I wanted to know where I could configure the custom rulesets for each of the projects? I currently don't have VS 2010 premium/ultimate so that I can make code-analysis a part of the solution.

Is there way where-in I can enable the different code-analysis rule-sets on the TFS server for each of the different projects?

-Sharath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No;  if you are using VS 2010 you will need the premium edition to do this with proper licensing. You might be able to do it by modifying the project file directly but you would need to know what to add to it manually.

If you have Premium edition then you can go to the code Analaysis tab of the project properties for each .Net project to select the rules and enable static code analysis.

You can install VS 2010 on your build machine and it will not take up an additional license id it is not used for development; You will actually need it installed there in order to run the analysis during your team build.

Another option is to install FxCop which is a free tool that is separate from Visual Studio. It has almost the same rules.  However it won't integrate with TFS as well.